# Get current computer's distinguished name in powershell without using the ActiveDirectory module

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that I need to find the full Distinguished name (`CN=MyComputer, OU=Computers, DC=vw, DC=local`) of the computer it is running on, however I can not guarantee that the `ActiveDirectory` module will be available on all computers that this script will be run on. Is there a way to get the current computer's full Distinguished name without using `Get-ADComputer $Env:COMPUTERNAME`?

---

Just in case this is a XY problem, what I am trying to do is move the computer to a specific OU, but I need a way to get the ASDI entry for the computer I am running on.

```
[ADSI]$computer = ("LDAP://" + $localDN)
if($Production)
{
    [ADSI]$destination = 'LDAP://ou=Production,ou=Computers,ou=VetWeb,dc=vw,dc=local'
    $computer.MoveTo($destination);
}
else
{
    [ADSI]$destination = 'LDAP://ou=Test,ou=Computers,ou=VetWeb,dc=vw,dc=local'
    $computer.MoveTo($destination);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this (requires v2):

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(cn=$env:COMPUTERNAME))"
([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Properties.distinguishedname
```

Comment: Thank you, that one works perfectly. In fact I don't even need the Properties.distingushedname, I just changed the second line to `$computer = [ADSI](([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().Path)` and I could use it with my `MoveTo` command.

Comment: Thanks. You could also get the computer object with: ([adsisearcher]$filter).FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()

Comment: This returned null for me.

Comment: These property names appear to be case-sensitive, so for example `distinguishedname` works, but not `distinguishedName`

Answer (score 5):

Be careful with the ADSIsearcher method. If you have two computers with the same name in different domains in the same forest (the issue that caused me to perform the search that returned this article), this method is not guaranteed to return the correct one. This method will simply search in AD for a computer with the name returned by the ComputerName Environment Variable. You need to be sure to cross-reference the domain to which the computer is joined if you are in an environment with multiple domains in a forest.

Moderator, this should really be a comment to the answer by Shay Levy, but I cannot make a comment because I am new.

Comment: Welcome on board. Once you reach 50 reputation you will be able to comment everywhere. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

The cmdlet Get-ADComputer (PS ver 2.0) can help.

```
PS:\> $(Get-ADComputer 'mycomputer').distinguishedName
```

The name of the computer should be the short name, like $env:COMPUTERNAME.

Comment: FYI: requires RSAT on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The only sure way I know to find the DistinguishedName of the computer is the following which must be run as an administrator:

```
gpresult /r /scope:computer | find "CN="
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$de = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ds.SearchRoot = $de
$ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(samAccountName=$($env:ComputerName)$))"
$ds.SearchScope = "SubTree"

$r = $ds.FindOne()

$r.Path
```

Comment: I try it but `$r` is null after the `FindOne()`, `FindAll()` also returns no results. The filter I get after variable expansion is `(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(samAccountName=(VWDEV)$))` does that look correct to you? I am not fully up to speed on LDAP queires but it seems odd to me to have a parenthesis between the computer name and the $

Comment: No, there shouldn't be parens around VWDEV. Change the filter to `"(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(samAccountName=$($env:ComputerName)$))"`

Answer (score 0):

Try This...Easy to understand and easy to remember as well.....

`$cn = Read-Host` "Enter the ComputerName"

`$cnObj = Get-ADComputer $cn`

`$ou = $cnObj.distinguishedname`

`$ou`

Comment: Isn't Get-ADComputer part of the active directory module which may or may not be installed on the system (the entire point of the question is to have a way that will always work and does not rely on "optional" modules)

Comment: @scott-chamberlain The module doesn't necessarily need to be installed. You can use implicit-remoting technique in PS. This way all cmdlets of ActiveDirectory module will work as if they are locally installed on your PC. Read More here: [TechTutsOnline](https://www.techtutsonline.com/implicit-remoting-windows-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\DataStore\Machine\0" -Name "DNName"
```

Comment: Why go to all that trouble rather than running this `get-computerinfo | select -Property csname`?

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes the simplest answer is the best

```
$(Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:COMPUTERNAME).DistinguishedName
```

I'm sure the command options have evolved across the years, but for someone trying to get the DistinguishedName in a batch or remote script, this may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

The [ADSystemInfo COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsadsysteminfo) will work and does not require any additional modules or initiate any LDAP searches

```
[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("ComputerName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, (New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"), $null)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get it from the environment by using:

```
$computer = gc env:computername
```

Or is this exactly what you don't want?  I'm terrible with powershell.

Comment: No that is the computer's common name, I need its **distinguished name**, I need "CN=MyComputer, DC=example,DC=com", your answer just returns "MyComputer"