# Powershell Selecting Certain Output

Tags: powershell

Just wondering how I can extract a certain line/text of output from Powershell. I am trying to get the OU of the PC without having Active Directory module installed on the PC running the script.

The only way I can think of is `GPResult /R` then extract the output.

So far I have:

```
GPResult /r /SCOPE:COMPUTER | Select-String OU=
```

Which returns:

> CN=PC-12345,OU=Test Devices,OU=Middle Layer,OU=Top
> Layer,OU=Equipment,DC=Test,DC=Lab

I need to select the `OU=Test Devices`, however every time I run the script the OU will be different so cannot search by the OU name itself.

Comment: Best practice is to use native PowerShell [cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview), if that doesn't exist, or isn't possible, use [.net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet) method and *only* as a *last* resource use external commands. In this case I recommend to use [ADSI](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/adsi/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi), see e.g.: [Get current computer's distinguished name in powershell without using the ActiveDirectory module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146959/1701026).